# Using VMIN and VTIME with Windows

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port, porting

I'm adapting a simple Linux serial library I wrote for cross-platform compatibility. Most things carry over (though Microsoft insists on renaming everything), but there are a few features I haven't been able to find.

My current problem is the usage of VMIN and VTIME (in `struct termios`). On Linux, I use them to force reads to block for a certain number of characters, but time out with an error if they aren't received. However, Windows recommends that the [`BuildCommDCB`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363143%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function be used instead of directly setting parameters for its [`DCB`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (device-control block) structure. That function doesn't support anything resembling VMIN or VTIME, and the `DCB` structure itself isn't much better.

Is there any way to get this functionality in Windows without implementing it myself? I'd rather not deal with managing serial interrupts and callbacks for only one platform in my library if it's at all avoidable.

EDIT: The [`SetCommTimeouts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function appears to emulate the features of VTIME, but I still haven't found anything for VMIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to perfectly emulate the case where VMIN=0 and VTIME=0, but I was able to recreate everything else accurately.

In the constructor of the class, after the `DCB` is initialized and applied (`timeout` is a [`COMMTIMEOUTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `readTimeout` and `readMinChars` are `unsigned char`s):

```
//Set read timeouts
if(readTimeout > 0) {
    if(readMinChars > 0) {  //Intercharacter timeout
        timeout.ReadIntervalTimeout = readTimeout * 100;    //Deciseconds to milliseconds
    } else {                //Total timeout
        timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = readTimeout * 100;   //Deciseconds to milliseconds
    }
} else {
    if(readMinChars > 0) {  //Counted read
        //Handled by length parameter of serialRead(); timeouts remain 0 (unused)
    } else {                //"Nonblocking" read
        timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;   //Wait as little as possible for a blocking read (1 millisecond)
    }
}
if(!SetCommTimeouts(handle, &timeout)) {
    printf("Error setting serial port timeout: %lu\n", GetLastError());
    throw std::runtime_error("serial initialization failed");
}
```

The complete serial class is available on Github, as part of a much larger project: [`serial.h`](https://github.com/Techwolfy/telepresence/blob/windows/util/serial.h) [`serial.cpp`](https://github.com/Techwolfy/telepresence/blob/windows/util/serial.cpp)

Comment: VMIN is minimum number of characters, the read length parameter is maximum! There is no equivalent on Windows afaik.
And for nonblocking read you need to use "a value of MAXDWORD, combined with zero values for both the ReadTotalTimeoutConstant and ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier members".